# Flask-HTTPAuth verify_password function not receiving username or password

Tags: python, flask, http-authentication, flask-httpauth

When I try access a route with the `@auth.login_required` decorator, I am prompted with a window to enter my username and password.  After entering this info, the parameters `username_or_token` and `password` for the `verify_password` function are `''`.  Why is the data empty?

```
@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username_or_token, password):
    # first try to authenticate by token
    user = USER.verify_auth_token(username_or_token)
    logger.debug("user = %r", user)
    logger.debug("Entered USEREMAIL = %r" ,  username_or_token)
    logger.debug("entered password = %r" ,  password)

    if not user:
        # try to authenticate with username/password
        user = session.query(USER).filter_by(USEREMAIL=username_or_token).first()   
        if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
            return False
    g.user = user
    return True
```

**UPDATE**

I've simplified the code to this:

```
@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    logger.debug("username = %s" % username)
    logger.debug("password = %s" % password)
    return true


@app.route('/api/token')
@auth.login_required
def get_auth_token():
    return "Hello, %s!" % auth.username()
```

I'm testing this function by using `Advanced Rest Client`.

`http://localhost:8081/myapp/api/token`

I also attached an `Authorization` header.

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Basic YXNkOmFzZA==
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4
```

This results in the output:

`Hello, !`

Log File:

```
username = 
password =
```

I am also never prompted to enter my `security credentials` anymore.

Another strange thing is that even if I change return to `false` in `verify_password`, I still get the same output: `Hello, !`

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a complete example that reproduces the problem. The username and password are set to empty strings only when the client does not send the `Authorization` header, so this could be a client-side issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experienced similar to OP.  If you're running with mod_wsgi, make sure to set `WSGIPassAuthorization On` as [documented here](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPassAuthorization).

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get username and password with this minimal example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@auth.verify_password
def foo(username, password):
    print "verifying...."
    print username
    print password
    return False

@app.route('/')
@auth.login_required
def index():
    return "Hello, %s!" % auth.username()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

However, while working on it, chrome saved cookies and I had to remove all cache including cookies, because I was getting automatically authenticated. Maybe this could cause you problems.

Also, don't forget to mark `@app.route("/")` with `@auth.login_required` decorator. Otherwise, the verify_password callback doesn't get called.

Comment: It also helps to add a sample HTML form that submits data to such an app.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when running my Flask app on EC2. So I guess you're running your app behind a wsgi service.
The point is wsgi will intercept every request header for different purposes so we need to do some configurations to make sure authentication header will be intact until it reach our app.
Thanks for the answer from Erik Stephens helped me solve this. I put WSGIPassAuthorization On to /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf on my EC2 instance and restart httpd service. You guys may want to have that update for only your app wsgi config file up to your configuration.
Hope this help someone with same problem when launching app to aws.

Answer (score 0):

The `@verify_password` callback should return `True` if you allow the user or `False` if you don't. In this function, an anonymous user (i.e. one that does not send authentication) is represented with empty strings for both the `username` and `password` fields.

In your code you are not verifying that the user credentials are valid. Instead, try something like this:

```
@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    logger.debug("username = %s" % username)
    logger.debug("password = %s" % password)
    if username == '':
        return False
    return true
```

The above will allow any combination of username/password, but will not let anonymous users in.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel. Using this does stop anonymous users. However, I still have the same issue with the `username` being `''`. This is how I send my request (need Chrome Advanced Rest Client): `chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/RestClient.html#RequestPlace:default`. When I send this, I am prompted with an `authorisation` screen. No matter what I type here and then click `Log In`, the box constantly reappears. When I finally press `Cancel`, I get the message `Unauthorised Access`.

Comment: @Giri: that's a behavior of the browser, anytime the server responds with a 401 status code the browser displays the login dialog box. An easy way to avoid this is to return a 403 status code instead of 401. You can do this in your Flask-HTTPAuth error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication example. This example demonstrates how to protect Flask endpoints with basic authentication, using secure hashed passwords. After running this example, visit `http://localhost:5000` in your browser. To gain access, you can use (username=john, password=hello) or (username=susan, password=bye).

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth 
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

app = Flask(name) 
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

users = { "john": generate_password_hash("hello"), "susan": generate_password_hash("bye") }

@auth.verify_password 
def verify_password(username, password): 
    if username in users: return check_password_hash(users.get(username), password) 
    else: return False

@app.route('/') 
@auth.login_required def index(): 
    return "Hello, %s!" % auth.username()

if name == 'main': 
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: you might want to format the code, especially for python.